# How to plot timeseries bar chart with multiple values per stack/ timestamp from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
                               value      cumsum   price
0    2021-02-01 00:00:00    164.6136    164.6136  0.0216
     2021-02-01 00:00:00    163.8085    328.4221  0.0215
     2021-02-01 00:00:00    163.0466    491.4687  0.0214
     2021-02-01 00:00:00  14999.9925  15491.4612  0.0213
1    2021-02-01 00:00:10    164.6136    164.6136  0.0216
...                              ...         ...     ...
8634 2021-02-01 23:59:00  14999.9993  14999.9993  0.0221
8635 2021-02-01 23:59:10  14999.9993  14999.9993  0.0221
8636 2021-02-01 23:59:20  14999.9993  14999.9993  0.0221
8637 2021-02-01 23:59:30      0.0000      0.0000  0.0221
     2021-02-01 23:59:30  14999.9993  14999.9993  0.0221
```

My data looks like the above, and I would like to plot a graph like below
[image]

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to plot the graph.

If the code helps you, accept it as answer and upvote it pls.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
 
# create data
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 20, 10, 26],['A', 10, 40, 10, 26],['A', 10, 70, 10, 26], ['B', 20, 25, 15, 21],['B', 20, 45, 15, 21], ['C', 12, 15, 19, 6],
                   ['D', 10, 18, 11, 19]],
                  columns=['Team', 'Round 1', 'Round 2', 'Round 3', 'Round 4'])
# view data
df

# # plot data in stack manner of bar type
df.pivot("Team", "Round 2").plot(kind='bar',stacked=True).legend().set_visible(False)


plt.show()
df
```

This is what you get as output. Do you expect this?

[image]